# How to perform testing on HTML Canvas element by Selenium WebDriver without to using coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, canvas, automation

I'm looking for a pretty and practical way to handle HTML Canvas elements as part of E2E automated testing.

The only way to handle it by what I've find on net is to click on X,Y coordinates and it's not a stable way because the canvas element in my use case contains a dynamic graph inside and i can't use the X,Y solution for this.

Please you help to find a better solution for this, thanks.

---

**Technical info -**

Webdriver - 3.4.0

Chrome driver - 2.29

Node JS - 7.8.0

JS - ES6

FW - Mocha + Chai